# frozen security warning dialog

Tags: java, applet

I have `applet` which deploy through `html` on client side.
 After update `jdk` with `jre` to latest version - `1.6.0_45` i got problem with frozen security warning dialog. When applet is loaded then dialog appears and all buttons (Yes, No, More information) on dialog not respond to clicks.

I did try to research which code is unsigned, but did not find the information how to do it. The only thing that I have found i can press `5` in java console but it do not output information that i need

I found that i can set in `java control panel` -> `security` -> `hide warnings and run with protection`, then dialog do not appear and applet runs normally.

Comment: does it work with `1.7.0_21`?

Comment: Yes it work. I solved this issue by adding in `MANIFEST`: `Trusted-Library: true`, but it just not invoke buggy window anymore